# Python for set globals()[''] variables having undefined name warning message

Tags: python, flycheck

I am using flycheck for for Python. For global files that I set using ( `globals()['variable']`), and later used, it gives the following warning message: `undefined name <variable> [F821]`

Example:

```
globals()['var1'] = "hello_world"
print(var1) # undefined name 'fID' [F821]
```

---

It underlines and colors it with red color.

[image]

---

Added lines to `.emacs`

```
(require 'flycheck)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
(setq-default flycheck-flake8-maximum-line-length 160)
(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")
(setq flycheck-emacs-lisp-load-path 'inherit)
```

Comment: There are nothing to do about it on Emacs side. It's from code checker. `flake8` I guess.

Comment: @muffinmad Should I ask this question on stackoverflow refering to `flake8`?

Comment: Yes, I think it will help solve your issue.

Comment: I have asked but community has removed my question :( @muffinmad

Answer (score 0):

A turnaround is to declare the variable.

```
# Make flake8 happy
if "var1" not in globals():
    var1 = None

globals()['var1'] = "hello_world"
print(var1)
```